# How can I stop the bootstrap 4 navbar from sticking to the top of the page when in mobile viewport?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want the navbar to be sticky on wide screen, and this works. I don't want it to collapse when on a mobile viewport. How can I make it so that the navbar simply unsticks from the top when on a small screen? Here is my HTML:

```
<div  class="navbar-light" style="position: sticky; top: 0px; background-color: #fff0d8;">  
<div class="container">
<ul class="sc-nav nav navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 flex-md-row">
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaa</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">bbbb</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ccc</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ddd</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">eee</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">ffffffffff</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#">sdasdasdasd</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: which bootstrap version are you using ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a **[media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)** to change the `position`  to `relative`. Note that you'll need `!important` to override your inline style declaration, as inline styles have the maximum level of **[specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)**.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) { /* Bootstrap's mobile view breakpoint */
  .navbar-light {
    position: relative !important;
  }
}
```

This can be seen in the following example:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .navbar-light {
    position: relative !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="navbar-light" style="position: sticky; top: 0px; background-color: #fff0d8;">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="sc-nav nav navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 flex-md-row">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaa</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">bbbb</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ccc</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ddd</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">eee</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ffffffffff</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">sdasdasdasd</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Yes. I wish I could give you a hug.

Answer (score 2):

- You could have used the built-in class `sticky-top`  https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/position/

> **Sticky top**
>
> Position an element at the top of the viewport, from edge to edge, but only after you scroll past it. The `.sticky-top` utility uses CSS’s `position: sticky`, which isn’t fully supported in all browsers.
>
> Microsoft Edge and IE11 will render `position: sticky` as `position: relative`. As such, we wrap the styles in a `@supports` query, limiting the stickiness to only browsers that properly can render it.
>
> `<div class="sticky-top">...</div>`

- and create a custom break point at `@media screen and (max-width: 767px)` to match `flex-md-row` break point.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#responsive-breakpoints

> // Extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 576px)
>
> // No media query since this is the default in Bootstrap
>
> // Small devices (landscape phones, 576px and up)
>
> @media (min-width: 576px) { ... }
>
> // Medium devices (tablets, 768px and up)
>
> @media (min-width: 768px) { ... }
>
> // Large devices (desktops, 992px and up)
>
> @media (min-width: 992px) { ... }
>
> // Extra large devices (large desktops, 1200px and up)
>
> @media (min-width: 1200px) { ... }

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sticky-top {
    position: relative !important;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<div class="navbar-light" style="background-color: #fff0d8;">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="sc-nav nav navbar-nav nav-fill w-100 flex-md-row sticky-top">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">aaa</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">bbbb</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ccc</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ddd</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">eee</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">ffffffffff</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">sdasdasdasd</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div style="height:200vh">give a scroll to the demo</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but AFAIK then I couldn't have my header image be above the menu, and then have the menu stick to the top when I scroll down. Obsidian Age got it though :)